How can I fix missing IAM permissions for Cloud Run Functions
I'm trying to create a Cloud Run Function, but whenever I try to deploy it, it gives me a few errors saying that the function was not fully deployed. It looks like they all stem from this permission error.

Could not build the function due to missing permissions.
generic::permission_denied: Caller does not have required permission
to use project my-project-id-1234. Grant the caller the
roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageConsumer role, or a custom role with
the serviceusage.services.use permission, by visiting
https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project?project=my-project-id-1234
and then retry. Propagation of the new permission may take a few
minutes.

Because of that error (I think) it was unable to initialize the underlying Cloud Run Service
Cloud Run service projects/my-project-id-1234/locations/us-central1/services/start-transcript for the function was not found. The function will not work correctly. Please redeploy.

and the Eventarc trigger that I'm using.
Eventarc trigger projects/my-project-id-1234/locations/us-central1/triggers/start-transcript-801754 for the function was not found. The function may not work correctly. Please redeploy.

Because the error doesn't specify who the caller is, I'm not sure what IAM principals to give the roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageConsumer role to. I've tried giving the role to my Google Cloud Functions Service Agent, but I don't think that did anything.
Looking at the logs also doesn't give any other information.
Thank you!
